# What are the upsides of storing one's assets in a cryptocurrency exchange?

Tags: cryptocurrency, crypto-exchanges

In the wake of the ongoing FTX debacle, I wonder the following: what are the upsides of storing one's assets in a cryptocurrency exchange?

Comment: I would question whether there *are* any.

Comment: @franck Demoncourt: please edit to clarify whether by "store one's assets" you meant storing cryptocurrency you already own, or converting additional assets to cryptocurrency form for storage? The two answers given so far could both be correct depending on which question you were asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Coinbase to store my cryptocurrency from 2016 to 2020. (I don't own any cryptocurrency anymore, and during that time period, Coinbase had an unblemished record.)

1. It was very easy to convert my cryptocurrency to dollars and vice-versa with Coinbase. I set up a transfer agreement between Coinbase and JP Morgan Chase for this.
2. My use case for cryptocurrency was to use it for specific, legal transactions. I used it mostly to buy things from Microsoft and reddit gold (little rewards or smileys for reddit users). reddit didn't accept credit cards and I didn't use PayPal at the time. Often, it was just more convenient and faster to make a transaction between Coinbase and Microsoft than to dig my credit card out of my purse in the other room. Also, I didn't want anyone in my household to know that I was making purchases from Microsoft, and since they were unfamiliar with cryptocurrency, it was less likely. Neither reddit nor Microsoft accept Bitcoin for payment now, so that use case is no longer valid.
3. It was very easy to do charting and basic analysis with the tools available on Coinbase's website, then execute my transaction.
4. Everyone that I knew who used wallets (instead of an exchange) would periodically "lose" transactions. By "lose", I mean that when they were a recipient, the funds didn't arrive; when they were the sender, the recipient didn't get the funds as expected. I never had that happen with Coinbase, not even once. I was also able to very quickly and credibly demonstrate that I had sent funds to a specific address or that I hadn't received them using Coinbase account tools.

Regarding item 4, one could say that the same is true for a bank. Yes, I know! And one could also say that using a centralized cryptocurrency exchange defeats the entire distributed, decentralized strengths of using cryptocurrency. I realize that but for my purposes, it was okay, as I was not fascinated by the intricacies of the blockchain.

Coinbase has a pleasant user interface, a lot better than what I have used for online banking or even brokerage services. Other than that, I used Coinbase much the way I use online banking services. Also, I didn't use Coinbase to store **all** my assets, only my cryptocurrency assets.

Answer (score 1):

I go with "there aren't any".

Cryptocurrency is not an investment or savings vehicle. It's either for value transfer as originally designed or, if you still believe it is going to gain value, for high-risk speculation.

Comment: objectively false answer

Comment: Some will disagree with me. Many, looking at the history of experience with crypto, will agree. At the very least you are discarding the insurance against loss that comes with a bank account.

Comment: The first sentence is objectively false, because two obvious upsides are low fees and receiving interest. The second paragraph is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Banks charge no fees for storing value. Unless you are getting enough interest to cancel out all the fees and conversion costs AND exceed what a bank can offer, you aren't winning. The second is a conclusion drawn about where crypto _may_ actually have value. Be glad I didn't say what many feel, that crypto is a Ponzi scheme.

Comment: banks are not exchanges. Stock brokers absolutely charge fees, and the trading fees are much lower than if you went and traded the stocks yourself on the open market - much like how cryptocurrency exchanges operate. "Low fees" means "Low trading fees" and not "Low account fees" because we are talking about exchanges and not banks.

Comment: Mutual funds can be purchased without going through a broker, by dealing directly with the issuing organization. I've been doing that for decades.No fee except the one built into the fund, often small fraction of a percent. We do need the querant to define what question they are asking, rather than trying to guess...

Comment: okay? I've never heard anyone say stock broker fees are scams because you can just get mutual funds instead

Comment: That's completely orthogonal to the points I was making.

Answer (score 0):

- It is convenient and easy.
- The risk of losing money is **much lower** if you are not technically savvy.
- You can (day-)trade with low or even zero fees.

  - The range of trading possibilities can be wider.
- Your transactions are not public.
- Some exchanges have something like a savings account that pays you interest.

Answer (score -1):

Upsides of storing one's assets in a cryptocurrency exchange from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/comments/yzpxap/daily_general_discussion_november_20_2022_gmt0/ix461k7/?context=3):

> - can't lose your keys, easier to understand for beginners, easier access to some services, like staking, for some coins. (source: [Terrible-Horse-70](https://www.reddit.com/user/Terrible-Horse-70))
> - Disaster recovery. For example if you die relatives can use the will and death certificate to take ownership of your crypto. If you self custody make sure you have foolproof plans for fire, flood, death, $5 wrench attack, pissed off spouse, compromised computer, user error and numerous other possibilities. (source: [OurNumber4](https://www.reddit.com/user/OurNumber4))

Comment: These are certainly advantages over having crypto stored as scribbled notes in your sock drawer or an obscure file in your PC. At least, until the crypto exchange is hacked or goes bankrupt, as has happened.

Comment: @keshlam are any advantages missing from the existing answers?

Comment: The problem I have with this answer is that it assumed the assets are going to be crypto. As I read the original question, it is about crypto _versus_ other ways of storing value. Perhaps the original poster could clarify which meaning they intended; that affects which of our answers (if any) is most applicable.